# How to host a SWF file from any page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, flash, asp.net-ajax

Is there a way to host a [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) game like [Bloons Tower Defense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloons#Bloons_Tower_Defense), onto my ASP.NET page? Can you somehow cache a page containing the .SWF file and then play it on that page?

Also is it legal to get any SWF file you want and play it on a different page, if you have credited the author?

I'm very new to this topic and want to create a website that will search for all avaliable, online games, and then play it on the page of my website.

How will I go about this approach? I have thought of creating foreign pages as a string through the WebRequest and WebResponse class, and then searching for the .swf, then downloading it to my server and rehosting it on a page, but that seems too much of a hassle and like it won't work.

What way should I use and how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not crazy, at least this is illegal. You can't host <strike>stealed</strike> content from other sites without the written approval of the copyright owner or conforming to its licence.

Talk to the site owner and ask him for his content and read the licence therms if any. This applies to any content you want from any other sources.

Answering your question: Don't do it! and Don't do it to yourself!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really looked at copyright terms yet. How do you go about asking the author? Do you just email them or is there some legit system to use?

Comment: Yes. Every site has a contact form or a "Contact the author" link. If yo can, try contacting the owner or artist in case of an image, a video or audio. For articles and blog entries, try contacting the author.